# MKAnnotationView's callout not refreshing properly

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've got a problem with the accessory views in the `MKAnnotationView`s, but it only occurs when using the iOS 3 SDK. The 3.1.3 version specifically.

I have a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` and I create instances of it the usual way:

```
SourceAnnotationView *annotationView = (SourceAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kDefaultSourceAnnotationID];

if (annotationView == nil) {
    #if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"RecordViewController viewForAnnotation source %d",[sourceAnnotation.ioiIdent intValue]);
    #endif

    annotationView = [[[SourceAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:sourceAnnotation reuseIdentifier:kDefaultSourceAnnotationID] autorelease];
    annotationView.delegate = self;
}
```

Later on in the code, I change the content of the callout bubble by doing:

```
UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kDeleteAudioButtonImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kAnnotationViewLeftAccessoryWidth, kAnnotationViewLeftAccessoryHeight);
deleteButton.tag = kDeleteAudioButtonTag;
deleteButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
deleteButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(calloutButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

selectedAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton;

UIButton *editAudioInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
editAudioInfoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kAnnotationViewRightAccessoryWidth, kAnnotationViewRightAccessoryHeight);
editAudioInfoButton.tag = kEditInfoButtonTag;
editAudioInfoButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
editAudioInfoButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[editAudioInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(calloutButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

selectedAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = editAudioInfoButton;
```

with `kAnnotationViewRightAccessoryWidth` and `kAnnotationViewRightAccessoryHeight` being both equal to 32.

When I no longer need these buttons, I try (and in most cases manage) to get rid of them like this:

```
selectedAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
selectedAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
```

In iOS 4, this results in the accessory views dissapearing and everything working beautifully. However, in iOS 3 the two buttons stay, even though they're not clickable, as if they were not completely removed from the callout's view.

Also, if I click any other annotation view the two buttons appear.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a picture of what happens:

[image]

Comment: In what method are you setting the callout accessory views to nil?

Comment: @Anna Karenina In method called when the right botton on the nav bar is clicked

Comment: So the code that sets the accessory views to buttons is in viewForAnnotation but the code that sets the accessories to nil is in nav bar button method, right?

Comment: @Anna Karenina The code that sets the accessory views isn't in viewForAnnotation either. Should it be there? Its in a method called when the same button is pressed. The flow goes like this:
Press button -> Add accessory views -> do some stuff -> press button -> remove accessory views.

Comment: So only the SourceAnnotationView alloc+init is in viewForAnnotation?  The problem may be that the setting of accessories is not in viewForAnnotation and when a view gets re-used things get screwed up.  How do you access selectedAnnotationView in the nav button method?  Do you have a property in your annotation class that you can set in the nav button method that can then be accessed in viewForAnnotation to decide whether to add/remove the accessories?

Comment: @Anna Karenina selectedAnnotationView is a member of the class that gets its value everytime an annotation becomes selected. Do you think that moving the addition and removal of the accessory views to `viewForAnnotation:` might solve this? I don't have such property but I could try that approach

Comment: Yes, I'd try adding that accessory-setting/clearing code to viewForAnnotation as well as doing it in the nav bar button method and setting an annotation property.

Comment: @Anna Karenina. I don't know how this got solved really. But if you want, write an answer summarizing these comments and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

make call after

```
 selectedAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
 selectedAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = nil;


[selectedAnnotationView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: is calloutButtonPressed called or not

Comment: Nope, they are visible but not touchable.